# Visualforce: Why the display of an PDF-File inside an IFRAME works on a Sandbox but not in Production?

Tags: visualforce, attachment, contentversion, files

On a Visualforce page I have an IFRAME like this:

```
<iframe class="viewer" src=""></iframe>
```

It starts up an shows nothing because src is blank. Good. To store the actual PDF I upload it as File (not the old Attachment). So technically I have a DocumentVersion which holds the blob of the pdf.

Now I use JS to update the src tag to show a PDF like this (where Id is set to a valid DocumentVersion id )

```
$('.viewer').attr('src',/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+id)
```

On the sandbox, it works like a charm: the pdf will be loaded inside the iframe as expected.

Now if I deploy the same code on Production, the following happens: the IFRAME is not updated, but the PDF is downloaded by the browser.

**The code I use is 100% identical - but behaves differently !!**

I found so far, that the code is NOT the reason for this. **The difference is caused just by the link I use.** This itself is behaving differently:

```
/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/ANY_VALID_CONTENTVERSION_ID_HERE
```

- On sandbox, chrome is using the internal PDF-Viewer to display the file. Which is what I want.
- On Production for a very short time (seconds only!) a new tab is opened and closed again and the PDF is downloaded instead of shown with the internal viewer.

I could not track it down, but I expect some headers are set differently by Salesforce causing that result.

Does anyone know more about the backgrounds on that or has encountered similar effects?

**EDIT 1**

I was able to dig deeper inside this issue inspecting the headers in detail as shown here: [Files: Why ContentVersion /sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/ sometimes sets Content-Disposition=attachment and sometimes =inline](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181594/files-why-contentversion-sfc-servlet-shepherd-document-download-sometimes-set)

Basic issue is, that Content-Disposition needs to be **inline** but on production it gets **attachment**.

Comment: any changes that VF security settings are different?

Comment: Yes.. can be CSP in critical updates

Comment: @kurunve none I was able to find - I checked a lot but might have missed something. Any important thing I should double check?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I've checked that this critical update is **enabled** on **both** (Sandbox and Production) and I still got the differences.

Comment: @UweHeim - were you able to get around this issue?

Comment: @RedDevil no, this issue is still a mystery. We gave up on this and reimplemented that process without any PDF... very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific settings in salesforce 'File Upload and Download Security' that can help you to choose download or show file.

[image]

There are 3 options of file download behavior:

1. Download (recommended): The file, regardless of file type, is always downloaded.
2. Execute in Browser: The file, regardless of file type, is displayed and executed automatically when accessed in a browser or through an HTTP request.
3. Hybrid: Salesforce Files are downloaded. Attachments and documents execute in the browser.

Please reference this link for more invo:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_type_security.htm&type=5